# Post NSNotification from console

Tags: ios, nsnotifications

**Is this possible to post a NSNotification under console, when app's paused?**

---

### *Why?*

I need to test the reachability of a server in my app (I'm using `Reachability.h`).

So, I wonder if I could post notification by myself at random moments, by pausing the program and execute

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"kReachabilityChangedNotification"
                                                        object:nil];
```

on the console, stopped on the main thread, to see if my ongoing downloads are well frozen.

I could :

- unplug my ethernet wire,
- turn the network off on my preference panel,
- create a button which throws notifications,
- post notification with timer,

but I wonder if a manual post would work.

As is, the command doesn't work on console, cause apparently *receiver 'NSNotificationCenter' is a forward class and corresponding @interface may not exist*.

---

Before I try to get around this :

- Would that be good practice?
- Someone already tried that?
- Would I be sure it runs on the main thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just type in the lldb debugger when paused:

```
expr (void)[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"kReachabilityChangedNotification" object:nil]
```

As for your other questions:

Good practice? You could [use the network link conditioner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659382/installing-apples-network-link-conditioner-tool) or set up your device to test various network conditions.

See [Posting on the main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813764/posting-nsnotification-on-the-main-thread)